# Cone-like Lower Bound for function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to \mathbf{R}$ be infinitely differentiable, non-negative, and have finitely many zeros. Additionally, let $(a,b)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$ be an arbitrary zero of $f$. Let
$$
\widetilde{f}(x,\xi) = \sum_{0\leq i+j< \infty}\frac{\partial^{i+j}f(a,b)}{\partial x^i \partial \xi^j}\frac{(x-a)^i(\xi-b)^j}{i!j!}
$$
denote the Taylor series of $f$ centered about the point $(a,b)$, which converges for points in the ball $B_{\delta}$ with radius $\delta>0$ and for such points we also have that $f(x,\xi) = \widetilde{f}(x,\xi)$. Now, further suppose that the first nonzero derivative of $f$ is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}f(a,b)$. Additionally, there exists an $n\geq 1$ such that $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}f(a,b) \ne 0$.

Now, do there exist positive constants $c,k, \widetilde{\delta}$ such that for $(x,\xi)\in B_{\widetilde{\delta}}$,
$$
|f(x,y)|\geq c ((x-a)^2+(\xi-b)^2)^{\frac{k}{2}}.
$$

Comment: I don’t know. A few remarks: if you assume that the taylor series agrees with $f$ in a small ball around $(a,b)$, then basically the assumption that $f$ has finitely many zeroes implies the hypothesis on $\partial^n/\partial x^n f$, and ensures that $n$ is even. Have you tried to attack the problem assuming first that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$? If the answer is positive, with $k=n$, then what you want to prove follows by splitting the taylor series into the truncation up to order $n$ and the remainder (which goes to zero faster than $(x^2+y^2)^{n/2}$).

Comment: So the question can be reduced to: if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with an isolated zero at $(a,b)$, then does the lower bound you wrote hold with $k=n$?

Comment: The specific function I'm interested in is not a polynomial, unfortunately. I was curious if this result holds in a more general setting than looking directly at my specific function.

Comment: Sure, that was not my point. Whay I was saying is that, if you prove the statement for polynomials first, then the statement should be true for any function……... Although, thinking about it, my argument is wrong (check my answer for an explanation and an interesting example). I will leave my comments just for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have an answer, but I will write an example that completely contradicts what I wrote in the comments.

Consider
$$ f(x,y)=x^6+y^2-2x^3y+x^{100}+y^{100}. $$

Then, $f$ has an isolated zero at $(0,0)$, and satisfies your hypotheses with $n=6$, but when you truncate the Taylor expansion to any order between $6$ and $100$, you get a function with zeroes all along the curve $\{y=x^3\}$. So, reasoning by approximating $f$ with a truncated Taylor series, and simply reducing the statement to the case where $f$ is a polynomial, is not so trivial. Dumb me.

*Remark 1*. You can see that in this case the bound from below holds with $k=100$, although not with $k=n$. So $k$ can be completely unrelated from $n$.

*Remark 2*. You can also see that the statement is not true if $f$ is not analytic close to the zero. Simply modify my example slightly: the function
$$ g(x,y)=x^6+y^2-2x^3y+e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)} $$
satisfies all your hypotheses (except that of being equal to its Taylor series around $(0,0)$), but does not have the lower bound you want for any $k>0$.

Comment: How are you sure that the bound does not hold with $k=n$? The lower bound only needs to hold for some small ball about $(0,0)$. It's not a proof, but plotting with Mathematica indicates that the lower bound with $k=6$ does hold, so your "Remark 1" is confusing.

Comment: The lower bound cannot hold with $k=6$. To see that rigorously, note that for $t\in\mathbb R$ you have $f(t,t^3)=t^{100}+t^{300}$: the vector $(t,t^3)$ has length approximately $t$ for small $t$, while the output $t^{100}+t^{300}$ goes to zero much, much faster than $t^6$. So the lower bound cannot hold unless $k\geq 100$. Maybe the plot does not show that because $t^6$ and $t^{100}$ look very similar for small $t$, idk.

Comment: I see. This is changing the question, but what if instead the inequality just needs to hold almost everywhere, so it can fail on a set of measure zero. Your counterexample only fails on a curve which has measure zero.

Comment: Unfortunately the functions involved in the inequality are continuous, so if the inequality holds almost everywhere, it holds at all points by continuity. So it is the same thing.